# Subtle Sample Space

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been self-studying probability and statistics using Sheldon Ross's "A First Course in Probability" for a while, yet I still have problems on recognizing sample spaces in some probability problems, especially those with games. (like: toss a die until it turns 6, what is the probability of ...)

Here are examples of problems I am struggling with:

> (1) A woman has $n$ keys, of which will open her door. 
>   (a) If she tries the keys at random, discarding those that do not work, what is the probability that she will open the door on her $k^{th}$ try?
>   (b) What if she does not discard previously tried keys?
>   (Problem 45 from Chapter 2)

I thought the sample space is infinite (all the sequences that each does not contain $k$ except the last number on that sequence), which is why I get confused.

> (2) Given 20 people, what is the probability that among the 12 months in the year, there are 4 months containing exactly 2 birthdays and 4 containing exactly 3 birthdays? (Problem 47 from Chapter 2)

Can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what **you** think the sample spaces are for these questions? Otherwise we won't know where you are stuck or what you're not getting...

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is exactly the kind of stuff we would be glad to see in the question.

Comment: Do not deface your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Your attempt seems to misunderstand the question. Here $k$ is unknown but fixed for all possible sequences of keys tried. If you assume that she stops after the $k$-th try, then all possible sequences are of length exactly $k$. That's already the sample space for (b). Once you restrict to those that don't have repeated keys, you would have your sample space for (a).

(2) Again, just figure out what are **all possible situations** that are relevant to the question. What does "relevant" mean? Well, the question is about some 20 people, and other people are not relevant. Also, it is only about their birthdays, so all other information about them is irrelevant. The sample space then is all possible birthday combinations. If there are $d$ possible birthdays for each person, there would be $d^n$ possible birthday combinations for $n$ people.